# Jquery several 'avalanched' checks needed for collapsed/ expander

Tags: jquery

css:

```
#container_im.collapsed{
    background-color:red;
    height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 227px;
}

#container_im.expanded{
    background-color:green;
    height: 348px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 227px;
}

#expanded_content{
    height:100px;
    color: yellow;
    display: none;
}

//default state
//expand box
#nav.closed {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

#nav.opened {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;   
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container_im" class="collapsed" >


    <div id="nav" class="closed">0</div>
    box 1 - click me    

    <div id="expanded_content">
        extra content only for collapsed state
    </div>

</div>
```

js:

```
    <div id="nav" class="closed">0</div>
    box 2 - click me    

    <div id="expanded_content">
        extra content only for collapsed state
    </div>

</div>




***//
$(document).bind("click", function(e) {
    $(e.target).closest("#container_im").toggleClass("expanded");
    $(e.target).closest("#expanded_content").show();
     $(e.target).closest("#nav").toggleClass("closed");
});***
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NsBWy/14/

Any JS guru that could help me fix this jquery code?

- Trying to display the text #expanded_content to display only when the selected box is clicked. And hide the complete #expanded_content div and all of its children upon another click ( toggle )
- Trying to restyle the #nav div and only the one currently clicked

Any good ideas on how to make it better are welcome also, 
a bit stuck on how to implement above features after trying some things from the manual its the combination of functions I don't see at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lots of things wrong in your approach.  Take a look at this working jsFiddle and then I'll writeup some of the things you had wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/A9rKm/

```
$("#box").delegate(".container", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded collapsed");
});
```

Things you had wrong:

1. You can only have one object with a given id so you should be using class names, not ids for common elements.
2. You can use `this` to access the clicked on item.
3. You don't want to be putting event handlers on the document if you can avoid it.  I created a common parent that you can put the event handler on and then used `.delegate()` from the version of jQuery you chose (1.5) to automatically filter them for me.  With jQuery 1.7+, you would use `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`.
4. You can use more than one class with `.toggleClass()` to toggle multiple classes at once.
5. `.closest()` looks up the parent chain, not anywhere else.  You use `.find()` if you're looking for children of a particular type.
6. You don't need to use so many separate classes that indicate the open/close state.  One class on a common parent can be used by CSS for all children.  Thus, I was able to eliminate all of the other class changes.
7. CSS comments must be of the form `/* comment here */`.  You can't use `//` for CSS comments.

Comment: This almost works correctly thanks, I put together the message rather late in the evening( night) so it was a bit of sloppy. Thx for pouting out delegate did not knew I could use it in this way